# How to use two buttons with the same event handler using a loop?

Tags: windows, forms

So i have to do a project in windows forms with two buttons that have the same event handler. The buttons are delete button and reset button. i dont know how to continue.

---

```
        if () 
        {
            textbox.Text = "Hello";
            Deletebutton.Enabled = true;
            Resetbutton.Enabled = false;

        }
        else
        {
            textbox.Text = "";
            Resetbutton.Enabled = true;
            Deletebutton.Enabled = false;

        }
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add a little bit of context and effort into your question to show you at least tried something :)

Comment: Please write the complete code. The code snippet you shared is not even a valid syntax in almost any language.

Answer (score 1):

Well the event for button_click has 2 arguments(sender & eventargs)
inside the body of the event handler, cast the sender to button like this:

```
var button=sender as Button;
```

then u have access to it's properties that u can use in the if(...) for example:

```
if(button.name=="some name")
```